# PJSIP not running in Windows Phone 8 background process

Tags: windows-phone-8, rtp, pjsip

I've studied the Windows ChatterBox sample app for Windows Phone 8 and I was able to write a small app to try out PJSIP. However I've run into a problem with the CallInProgressAgent. When creating an outgoing call, I create a VoipPhoneCall object by calling the RequestOutgoingCall method on the VoipCallCoordinator class, thereafter I create the pjsip call by using the pjsua api. It seems pjsip looses all rtp connectivity as soon as I call the RequestOutgoingCall method. My guess is that pjsip is unable to run in a background process initiated by calling the RequestOutgoingCall method. Can anybody shed more light on this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the pjsip website:

***Windows Phone 8 (WP8) support is being added and is still under development on projects/winphone branch. Specific considerations for this platform are:
WP8 governs specific interaction with WP8 GUI and framework that needs to be followed by application in order to make VoIP call work seamlessly on the device. Some lightweight process will be created by WP8 framework in order for background call to work and PJSIP needs to put its background processing in this process’ context. Currently this feature is under development.***

The moral of this story is that we cannot use PJSIP in an application until the above background process development is complete.

Comment: Hi Houston, if you guys didn't use PJSIP, then what did you guys end up for WP8 voip app?

Comment: You can use duobango or linphone but both have hefty price tags. We're gonna wait for PJSIP.

Comment: We used PJSIP but only used minimum Windows Chatterbox Backgrounding code, and use simple Push Notification MPNS to wake app up when theres an incoming call.