# How to integrate PJSIP with VOIP chatterbox sample app Windows Phone 8

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, voip, pjsip

I am trying to integrate PJSIP with Voip chatterbox sample app Windows Phone 8. I can make a call but i cannot hear receivers voice nor he can hear mine. I am still not able to figure out how to safely remove audio loopback from sample app. Before doing this I made a simple app with UI and WinRT and made call using pjsip, i was able to send and receive audio.
PS- I used my app to call and receiver used linphone windows phone app.
Can any one tell me how to remove loopback and send and receive audio?

Answer (score 1):

PJSIP needs to add background support for WP8.   It might be a little while before this is supported.

Try

[PJSIP not running in Windows Phone 8 background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068922/pjsip-not-running-in-windows-phone-8-background-process/29928466?noredirect=1#comment48184543_29928466)

Also see,

The PJSIP code will handle all of the actual SIP and RTP code for you.  Like registering with your sip server, receiving and placing calls.  Basically you want to remove the telnet interface and call methods directly off of PJSUA interface.  You will want to extend the Globals.cpp class to add the methods you need to make phone calls.

The Chatterbox code is to add things like the incoming call screen and call state and awakening when the App is backgrounded.

You want to reference the Agents and Backend dlls.  Also make sure to set up your capabilities and other settings the exact same way as the Chatterbox UI project, see WPAppManifest.xml.  Lastly make sure you add the Contact Image and Ringtone files as content to your main project, or else the incoming call screen will not launch.